# Please help to send checklist to service without changing the model value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have a json array like

```
$scope.tablesData = [
                         {
                             "table_name": 'table1',
                             "charts": 0,
                             "flex_sheet": 0,
                             "dtf": 0
                             },{
                                 "table_name": 'table2',
                                 "charts": 1,
                                 "flex_sheet": 1,
                                 "dtf": 1
                             },{
                                 "table_name": 'table3'

                             },{
                                 "table_name": 'table4'

                             },
                             {
                                 "table_name": 'table5'

                             }]
```

I have html page like this

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table class="table">
    <thead class="table-inverse">
      <tr>
        <th>Table Name</th>
        <th>Charts</th>
        <th>FlexSheet</th>
        <th>Dtf</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="table in tablesData">
          <td>{{table.table_name}}</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value='0'                     ng-model="table.charts"></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value='0'  ng-model="table.flex_sheet"></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value='0' ng-model="table.dtf"></td>
       </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>

 <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="submit" ng-  click="upadateTableInfo()">

</div>
```

You can see this by http://jsfiddle.net/soumyagangamwar/gpm72kmo/

I have to send table data to service in submit click.
So I called **'updateTableInfo'** method in **ng-click**.

Please observe data i.e `$scope.tableData` once.  After controller is loading after getting data in view if I checked some values like rows 3,4,5 (table 3,4,5) then click submit button then controller receives the one array contain 5 objects each object contain 4 properties like table_name, charts, fles_sheet, dtf with thiere values. it's receives fine.

My problem is after view loading. If I didn't change any values(3,4,5) then in submit click I receive the array contain 5 objects but in that I receive 3,4,5 objects with out have properties charta, flex sheet, dtf. But if user not doing any thing then I have to send **0** to post method but object should contain all 4 properties.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the ng-init to set the modal values by default to 0 as follows. I hope it solves your problem.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="table in tablesData">
        <td>{{table.table_name}}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-init="table.charts = 0"  ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value='0' ng-model="table.charts"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-init="table.flex_sheet = 0" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value='0'  ng-model="table.flex_sheet"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-init="table.dtf = 0" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value='0' ng-model="table.dtf"></td>
 </tr>
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gpm72kmo/1/

Comment: But I don't want to change values defaultly. If I use ng-init then all check box values defaultly contain 0.

Comment: Can you tell why you don't want to change values by default. What are you trying to achieve actually ?

Comment: If object not contain the value then I have to set it as 0 in my view,  but If not contain value then I have to initialize that value in my view.